# Handling Multiple Forms on One Page

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="action=save&amp;id=239" id="save-form">
    <input type="text" value="0" name="views" /> <input type="submit" value="save plz" name="save" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="action=save&amp;id=862" id="save-form">
    <input type="text" value="3" name="views" /> <input type="submit" value="save plz" name="save" />
</form>
<form method="post" action="action=save&amp;id=12" id="save-form">
    <input type="text" value="2" name="views" /> <input type="submit" value="save plz" name="save" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_GET["action"] == "save") {
    if (isset($_GET["id"]) && preg_match("/^\d+$/", $_GET["id"])) {
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        // update view count here
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#save-form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {      
        //
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //
    }
});
```

I'm using this plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html

I realize right now all of my forms share the same id `save-form`. This code works great for the first instance of `save-form`. But I want it to work for all of them. Which brings me to my main question:

How can I modify my current jQuery/HTML to process each individual form.

Ideally I'd have a unique id, for example `save-form-239` and `save-form-862`. But I don't want to have to write `$('#save-form-239')` and `$('#save-form-262');` for every form.. what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if I'm sure dbaseman's solution works fine, it is usually best to avoid having multiple elements with the same ID, as it is invalid according the HTML specs.

A cleaner solution would be to use `class="save-form"` instead of `id="save-form"`, and then do `$('.save-form').ajaxForm(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You can write the selector like this to get an individual form:

```
$('[id=save-form]').eq(0);
```

(using the explicit attribute selector rather than the "#" shortcut allows JQuery to pull all of the elements with a matching ID)

I guess you would want something like this to process each form:

```
$('[id=save-form]').each(function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {      
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
});
```